Imprimir 80 valores aleatorios
Estoy aprendiendo Python. Necesito imprimir 80 numeros aleatorios de 100, sin importar que se repitan. Intento esto pero me imprime un solo numero.
import random 

sample_list_2 = []
for i in range(80):
    n = random.randint(0,100);
sample_list_2.append(n)

print(sample_list_2)


El problema es tu indentación, sample_list_2.append(n) debe ir adentro del for.

Porque estás asignando 80 veces la variable n y luego la agregas a la lista. Debería ser:
for i in range(80):
    n = random.randint(0,100);
    sample_list_2.append(n)

Recuerda que la indentación es importante.
O si prefieres usar list comprehension:
sample_list_2 = [random.randint(0,100) for i in range(80)]


aaaah, muchísimas gracias, de verdad.
